# ker (tr (.)) = [F (H),F (H)]

Tags: functional-analysis

Let H be Hilbert space and tr (.) be operator trace. Then ker (tr (.)) = [F (H), F (H)], where F (H) denotes the space of finite rank operators and  [F (H),F (H)] denotes commutator subspace.

Comment: @Joshkeneda I' m trying. check [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_trace).... It is written that, with the use of spectral condition, we can show that the kernel of the operator trace tr and the commutator subspace of the finite rank operators are equal, i.e.,  ker tr = [F(H), F(H)]

Comment: @JoshKeneda I' m trying..... check [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_trace)... it is written, by using the spectral condition, we can prove that the kernel of the operator trace tr and the commutator subspace of the finite rank operators are equal, i.e.,  ker tr = [F(H), F(H)].

Comment: And are you trying to prove it specifically using that spectral condition, or are you just looking for a proof that they're equal?

Comment: I am looking for a prove.... Is there is any other way? Please help.

Comment: There's an elementary proof that $tr(A) = 0$ implies $A$ is a commutator [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf).  This shows that $ker(tr) \subset [F(H), F(H)]$, and the opposite inclusion should be clear.